# Spring Session Creation

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-session

```
spring.session.store-type=jdbc
# Database schema initialization mode.
spring.session.jdbc.initialize-schema=always
# Path to the SQL file to use to initialize the database schema.
spring.session.jdbc.schema=classpath:org/springframework/session/jdbc/schema-mysql.sql
# Name of the database table used to store sessions.
spring.session.jdbc.table-name=SPRING_SESSION
spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true
```

The above is my configuration in `application.properties`. When the application runs, Spring creates a session and persists it automatically in the `Spring_sessio`n and `spring_session_attributes` table. My question is, can I tell Spring to do not persist the session details into the Database, and instead I create and save it to the same tables using JPA?

Thank you.

Comment: Look at JdbcSessionConfiguration, JdbcSessionDataSourceInitializer classes under Spring Boot. You will need to override JdbcSessionDataSourceInitializer and create your own bean to perform your custom logic

Comment: @gtiwari333 Thank you for your reply. May I get more information on how can I create and save the session details to the table using JPA? I looked into JdbcSessionDataSourceInitializer  but I am not very sure on how can I do that.